# How to obtain a solution of a set of coupled 4th order odes and algebraic equations

Tags: matlab, ode, nonlinear-optimization, runge-kutta

I have set of three equations that need to be solved simultaneously  to obtain results for six variables. It is actually a system of equations with one 4th order equation and one algebraic equation. The details about the problem description:
[image]
[image]

I have written the code for this problem by unsuccessfully linking ODE with other two equations as:

```
%.......Define Guess values for Two algebraic equations No.2 and 3.........%
global gus_value mass_flux_save 
gus_value =[0.0001, 334];
mass_flux_save=[];

%.......Initial Bounderies to ODE.........%
first_ivp =0.8*10^-9;      % sigma at x=0
second_ivp = 1*10^-11;     % d_sigma at at x=0
third_ivp =  1*10^4;       % dd_sigma at at x=0
forth_ivp =  0.008;        % ddd_sigma at at x=0
y0 =[first_ivp ;second_ivp;third_ivp;forth_ivp];

%.......Integeration limits/span of ODE.........%
xi =0;
xf =10*10^-9;

%...................ODE Solution Eq. No.1................%
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-10,'AbsTol',1e-20,'InitialStep',1e-15,'MaxStep',.1*(xf-xi),'Refine',5);
[xs,ys] = ode45(@(x,Y) forthorder_equa(x,Y),[xi  xf],y0,options);

%....................Ploting Results............%
axis1 = subplot(2,1,1); 
plot(axis1,xs,ys(:,1));
title(axis1,'x vs sigma');
ylabel(axis1,'sigma');
xlabel(axis1,'x');
axis2 = subplot(2,1,2);
plot(axis2,mass_flux_save(:,1),mass_flux_save(:,2),'--');
title(axis2,'x vs mass flux');
ylabel(axis2,'mass flux');
xlabel(axis2,'x');
%.......ENd.........%

function dy =forthorder_equa(x,Y)
%..............Properties Defination...............%
v = 0.000282/958.31;%viscosity
sur_ten = 7.264*10^-2;%Surface Tension
A = -8.7*10^-20;%Hammaker Constant

%..............Calling Global Varaibles...............%
global gus_value  mass_flux_save
delta_sigma = Y;

%..............Calling set of Non linear Equation Function...............%
non_fun = @(u)nonlinear_equation_p_m_T(u,delta_sigma);

%..............Solving set of Non linear Equations Eq.2 and 3...............%
intial_gus =[ gus_value(1),gus_value(2)];
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');
options = optimoptions(options,'MaxIterations', 1000);
options = optimoptions(options,'OptimalityTolerance', 1e-10);
options = optimoptions(options,'FunctionTolerance', 1e-3);
options = optimoptions(options,'StepTolerance', 1e-3);
options = optimoptions(options,'FunValCheck', 'off');
options = optimoptions(options,'Algorithm', 'trust-region-dogleg','Display','off');
i = fsolve(non_fun,intial_gus,options);
mass_flux = i(1); 
gus_value =[i(1), i(2)];
mass_flux_save = [mass_flux_save;x,i(1)] ;  

%..............Decompostion of 4th order ODE Equation No.1...............%
first=Y(2);
second=Y(3);
third=Y(4);
forth=-(3*(A*(Y(2)^2 + 1)^(7/2)*Y(2)^2 + 5*sur_ten*Y(1)^5*Y(2)^2*Y(3)^3 - mass_flux*v*(Y(2)^2 + 1)^(7/2)*Y(1)^2 + sur_ten*Y(1)^4*Y(2)*Y(4) - sur_ten*(Y(2)^2 + 1)*Y(1)^5*Y(3)^3 + 2*sur_ten*Y(1)^4*Y(2)^3*Y(4) + sur_ten*Y(1)^4*Y(2)^5*Y(4) - A*(Y(2)^2 + 1)^(7/2)*Y(1)*Y(3) - 3*sur_ten*(Y(2)^2 + 1)*Y(1)^4*Y(2)^2*Y(3)^2 - 3*sur_ten*(Y(2)^2 + 1)*Y(1)^5*Y(2)*Y(3)*Y(4)))/(sur_ten*Y(1)^5*(2*Y(2)^2 + Y(2)^4 + 1));
dy = [first;second;third;forth];

function F = nonlinear_equation_p_m_T(u,delta_sigma)
%..............Properties Defination...............%
M = 0.018;
R = 8.314;
P_v= 1.88 *10^4;
T_v= 333;
T_w = 334;
A = -8.7*10^-20;
k_l = .68;
h_fg = 2.358*10^6;
sur_ten = 7.264*10^-2;
Vm=0.022;

%..............Finding Constants...............%
a=((M/(2*pi*R)^0.5)*((P_v*Vm)/(R*T_v)));
b=((M/(2*pi*R)^0.5)*((P_v*M*h_fg)/(R)));

%..............Calling delta_sigma from forth order equation function...............%
P_d = A/delta_sigma(1)^3;
P_c  = sur_ten*(delta_sigma(3)*(1+(delta_sigma(2))^2)^-1.5);

%.............Non Linear Equations(Eq.2 and 3)..........................%
F(1) =  u(1)*(u(2)^1.5)-(a*(u(2)-T_v))+(b*(P_d+P_c));
F(2)  = u(1)*h_fg-(((k_l*(T_w-u(2)))/delta_sigma(1)));
```

The expected Results of this program should be as following:
[image]

However, I failed to get the required results as:
[image]

Comment: Why is there a non-canceled `delta''` in the middle term in the first equation? Apart from that, the question is almost surely off-topic here, as the task seems to be to find a suitable first order ODE system or at least a formulation as semi-explicit index-1 DAE system. This is more on-topic on scicomp.SE or math.SE.

Comment: Also, in the last denominator of equation 2, is the power 1.5 correct? In view of equation 1, a power -1.5 seems more plausible. Does there exist a derivation from physical first principles, an Euler-Lagrange formulation perhaps?

Comment: @LutzL Thank you so much for the suggestions. Yeah the bracket need to opened for that. I need a numerical coupling code in this regard i will consider to post there too.Thanks

Comment: Please mark cross-posts and give a link; and close questions if you found a satisfying answer elsewhere.

Comment: @LutzL The denominator power is correct and it has been solved by other guys as well. Why we need to take derivative of Tint (x)?It is algebraic variable?

Comment: @LutzL Okay i will try to find it and tell you then.Thanks

Comment: I check those places too, its just a question of the content of a question. And that answer efforts are not duplicated. Implementation of an algorithm is here or codereview, design of an algorithm including preparation of a problem is more scicomp, the mathematical site is of course math.

Comment: I suggest to put all your constants in 2 and 3 equations and see if they equal. There might be a problem with constants

Comment: @shade Thank you once again. Yeah i have validated these constants are to be correct. Actually in eq 2 i need to know delta derivatives to ensure that process.But  i have given the results from others with similar constants.